# How do I stop my Android app with a Room database from crashing?

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I'm writing an app that uses a Room database to store calendar events and notices. I feel like I've followed Google's tutorials to the letter (and looked at sunflower for inspiration), but any attempt to access the database crashes the app with no obvious way to tell what went wrong or how to fix it.

Here's my AppDatabase class:

```
package com.dmlpcb.familiar.data

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import com.dmlpcb.familiar.entities.CalendarEvent
import com.dmlpcb.familiar.entities.Notice

@Database(entities = [Notice::class, CalendarEvent::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun noticeDao(): NoticeDao
    abstract fun calendarEventDao(): CalendarEventDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile private var instance: AppDatabase? = null //for singleton

        fun getInstance(context: Context) : AppDatabase {
            return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
            }
        }

        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            return androidx.room.Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "familiar.db").allowMainThreadQueries().build()
        }
    }

}
```

Here's CalendarEventDao:

```
package com.dmlpcb.familiar.data

import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Delete
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.Query
import com.dmlpcb.familiar.entities.CalendarEvent

@Dao
interface CalendarEventDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM calendarEvent")
    fun getAll(): List<CalendarEvent>

    @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg calendarEvents: CalendarEvent)

    @Delete
    fun delete(calendarEvent: CalendarEvent)
}
```

Here's NoticeDao:

```
package com.dmlpcb.familiar.data

import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Delete
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.Query
import com.dmlpcb.familiar.entities.Notice

@Dao
interface NoticeDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM notice")
    fun getAll(): List<Notice>

    @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg notices: Notice)

    @Delete
    fun delete(notice: Notice)
}
```

Here's CalendarEvent:

```
package com.dmlpcb.familiar.entities

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import java.time.Duration
import java.util.Calendar

@Entity
//this data class is for the calendar events. It contains start time, duration, title, description, confirmed and isConfirmable
data class CalendarEvent(
    @PrimaryKey val uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "startTime") val startTime: Calendar?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "duration") val duration: Duration?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description") val description: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "confirmed") val confirmed: Boolean?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "isConfirmable") val isConfirmable: Boolean?
)
```

Here's Notice:

```
package com.dmlpcb.familiar.entities

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity
data class Notice(
    @PrimaryKey val uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "content") val content: String?
)
```

Here's build.gradle:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.dmlpcb.familiar"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.dmlpcb.familiar"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

    val room_version ="2.5.2"
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
}
```

There's nothing in my MainActivity yet aside from what is automatically generated. Any attempt to use the Room database results in the app instantly crashing at the first line of code that tries to access it.

I tried to use the full code from google for using a Room database but that is not possible.

Comment: Can you show the stack trace from the log? That will point to the issue.

Comment: There is none. That's a big part of my problem. How would I enable that?

Comment: Ok I think I've made some progress on this. I get this output when I try `val db = AppDatabase.getInstance(this)`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dmlpcb.familiar/com.dmlpcb.familiar.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find implementation for com.dmlpcb.familiar.data.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues with the build gradle:-

1. You are using `annotationProcessor` instead of the `kapt`.

   1. i.e. the annotaionProcessor is for Java not Kotlin

      1. an alternative is to utilise KSP rather than KAPT but that would require more changes to implement.
2. You have omitted the room ktx library
3. You are using `val` instead of `def` for defining the room_version

To resolve 1 you need to add the kapt plugin and then use `kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"` not `annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")`

To resolve 2 you need to add `implementation ("androidx.room:room-ktx:${room_version}")`

To resolve 3 change from `val room_version ="2.5.2"` to `def room_version = "2.5.2"`

***see the Working Demo below for a working build.gradle***

It is suggested that before running that you always compile (CTRL + F9) and check the build output (it appears that you just run the App)

**Still more Issues**

At this stage you will have issues as there are no **`TypeConverters`** for the two fields **startTime** and **duration** for the **CalendarEvent** class.

- Room can only store certain types

  - Null,
  - TEXT (such as String),
  - INTEGER (such as Int Long, Byte),
  - REAL (decimal types such as Double, Float) or
  - BLOB (byte streams such as ByteArray)).

Other objects such as Calendar have to be converted to one of the above

- null is useless as it can only represent 1 value i.e. null
- TEXT could be, and is often, a JSON representation of the Object
- INTEGER can be useful, especially for times/dates where a Long can very likely be used to represent all possible useful values
- FLOAT can be useful and may be preferable in some cases to INTEGER
- BLOB can also be useful but

For example you could utilise a TypeConverter for Calendar by storing the value as a Long.

To utilise a Type Converter you need to

1. have a class (or classes) in which functions are defined.
2. have 2 functions

   1. one to convert from the object type to the type to be stored (for our savings as a Long then it would convert a Calendar object to a Long)
   2. another to convert from the stored type to the object type (Long to Calander)
3. Each function needs to be preceded with the `@TypeConverter` annotation (**NOTE SINGULAR**)
4. The class(es) have to be defined via an `@TypeConverters` annotation (**NOTE PLURAL**).

So you could, for example have **1,2 and 3** a class such as:-

```
class RoomTypeConverters{

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromCalendarToLong(calendar: Calendar?): Long? {
        if (calendar==null) return null
        return Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis
    }
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTimeInMillisToCalendar(timeInMillis: Long?): Calendar? {
        if (timeInMillis==null) return null
        val rv = Calendar.getInstance()
        rv.timeInMillis = timeInMillis
        return rv
    }
}
```

- note these could probably be simplified
- each of the two do as the function name describes (the function name could be briefer/different to suit conventions/style etc)

For **4** the `@TypeConverters` annotation (**PLURAL**) has scope, so can be placed accordingly. The highest scope is when the placement is at the `@Database` annotation level so for this greatest scope you could have:-

```
@TypeConverters(RoomTypeConverters::class)
@Database(entities = [Notice::class, CalendarEvent::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false) 
....
```

- see https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/TypeConverters for more

**Working Demo**

The following is a working example using (as per the answer with some comments):-

A modified **build.gradle**:-

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt' /*<<<<< added */
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "a.a.so76924059kotlinroomcrash"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    def room_version = "2.5.2" /*<<<<< not val room_version = "2.5.2" */
    implementation ("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")
    implementation ("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
    kapt ("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version") /*<<<<< requires addition plugin above (top)*/
}
```

A modified **CalendarEvent** class (with the duration field commented out for brevity and convenience):-

```
@Entity
//this data class is for the calendar events. It contains start time, duration, title, description, confirmed and isConfirmable
data class CalendarEvent(
    @PrimaryKey val uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "startTime") val startTime: Calendar?,
   //@ColumnInfo(name = "duration") val duration: Duration?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description") val description: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "confirmed") val confirmed: Boolean?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "isConfirmable") val isConfirmable: Boolean?
)
```

The **RoomTypeConverters** class as above.

The **TypeConverters** annotation preceding the `@Database` annotation.

Some Activity code (**MainActivity**) to add some data to the database and to then extract the data writing the results to the log:-

```
const val TAG = "DBINFO"
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: AppDatabase
    lateinit var noticeDao: NoticeDao
    lateinit var calendarEventDao: CalendarEventDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = AppDatabase.getInstance(this)
        noticeDao = db.noticeDao()
        calendarEventDao = db.calendarEventDao()

        noticeDao.insertAll(
            Notice(1,"Notice1","content1"),
            Notice(2,"Notice2","content2")
        )
        calendarEventDao.insertAll(
            CalendarEvent(100,Calendar.getInstance(),"Cal100","Desc100",true,true),
            CalendarEvent(101,null,null,null,null,null)
        )
        for (n in noticeDao.getAll()) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Notice UID=${n.uid} TITLE is ${n.title} CONTENT is ${n.content} ")
        }
        for (c in calendarEventDao.getAll()) {
            Log.d(TAG,"CE UID is ${c.uid} TITLE is ${c.title} DESC is ${c.description} STARTTIME is ${c.startTime} CONF is ${c.isConfirmable} CONFIRMABLE IS ${c.isConfirmable}")
        }
    }
}
```

**All other code from your question included ASIS**.

**RESULTS**
When run (only intended to be run once otherwise you will encounter failures due to the unique constraints) then the log includes:-

```
2023-08-18 10:04:00.786 D/DBINFO: Notice UID=1 TITLE is Notice1 CONTENT is content1 
2023-08-18 10:04:00.786 D/DBINFO: Notice UID=2 TITLE is Notice2 CONTENT is content2 


2023-08-18 10:04:00.788 D/DBINFO: CE UID is 100 TITLE is Cal100 DESC is Desc100 STARTTIME is java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1692317040776,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=libcore.util.ZoneInfo[id="Australia/Sydney",mRawOffset=36000000,mEarliestRawOffset=36000000,mUseDst=true,mDstSavings=3600000,transitions=141],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2023,MONTH=7,WEEK_OF_YEAR=33,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=18,DAY_OF_YEAR=230,DAY_OF_WEEK=6,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=0,HOUR=10,HOUR_OF_DAY=10,MINUTE=4,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=776,ZONE_OFFSET=36000000,DST_OFFSET=0] CONF is true CONFIRMABLE IS true
2023-08-18 10:04:00.788 D/DBINFO: CE UID is 101 TITLE is null DESC is null STARTTIME is null CONF is null CONFIRMABLE IS null
```

i.e. as expected the tow Notices and two CalendarEvents have been extracted and reported upon.

using **AppInspection** the database itself looks like:-

[image]

and for the Notice table :-

[image]

**Warning**

If the above were run a second time then a failure would occur because a Notice with the uid **100** already exists *(a Primary Key is implicitly UNIQUE)* as per:-

```
2023-08-18 10:24:09.925 8924-8924/a.a.so76924059kotlinroomcrash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: a.a.so76924059kotlinroomcrash, PID: 8924
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{a.a.so76924059kotlinroomcrash/a.a.so76924059kotlinroomcrash.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: Notice.uid (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
```

**Note** The above does not address the issue that you will have due to no TypeConverter for the duration field of the CalendarEvent.

A suggestion is that you follow the answer and get a working version up and running and then progress to the stage of adding the duration field and the TypeConverter and if necessary ask another question if you then have issues.

- i.e. slowly progress (modify code, compile and then run (uninstalling the App to save writing migrations/changing the version)).
- As can be seen progressing with lots of code can result in a stream of errors.